# Open URL with Electron in non-default Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I am using Electron to try and open a URL. I know I can do something like

```
const { shell } = require('electron')

shell.openExternal('https://github.com')
```

to open the URL in the default browser.

Is there any way to do this in the non-default browser? For example, if I want to open a link to the Edge Store, but my default browser is Chrome, can I do something like

```
const { shell } = require('electron')

shell.openExternal('microsoft-edge:https://github.com')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do that with just default `shell`, because as far as I know it relies entirely on user system defaults, but there are existing npm packages like [open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) that will give you this functionality, with something like:

`await open('microsoft-edge:https://github.com');`

Their documentation will walk you through how to get this working.

Comment: But the docs say (now) not to use it with Electron... (To use `shell.openPath` instead) :thinking: